# Encrypting communication between between Microservice in my company and AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, node.js, encryption, angular

I am dealing with communication between microservices.
**Microservice A - Angular6/django**
**Microservice B - NodeJS**

My Microservice A is in company network and Microservice B is in AWS.
we need to find a way to communicate between them securely like using VPN or other encryption.
what is the best way to architecture this communication?

Comment: https perhaps ?

Comment: but my microservice A is in my company's network and it's not communication between AWS. Actually i'm not sure, if https is possible can you tell how?

Comment: i'm just trying for my internship, they said that they can't figure this out so if i can solve this problem i will get internship there. and i said about https the moment they asked me but about are the replies i got from the project manager!! @jfriend00

Comment: If the company network has internet access, then you should be able to make an https connection from A (on company network) to B (at AWS).  If the company network doesn't have internet access, then I don't know what you expect us to help you with.  You need network connectivity first.

Comment: yes, they will be having internet access!! @jfriend00

Comment: You can either establish a VPN between your company and AWS, using their IPSEC gateway for example, or public microservice B on a public IP on amazon and use HTTPS. If you had multiple services to publish you could put a reverse proxy on the public IP on AWS and do name based routing to the appropriate container. You can also use the load balancer AWS gives you when running an ingress on AKS